# iOS Customizing PKRevealController to work like Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to imitate the new Google Maps app where there's a button with 3 dots that you can pull to the left to reveal a new view controller on the right side with some settings for the app.

I have the default implementation of PKRevealController working..but since my front view controller has a map that takes up the entire screen's bounds... i can't tug left (instead, the map moves). I know it works because I have a button on the map that I can tug to the left to reveal my view controller that's on the right.

How do I change the way PKRevealController works so that it will only show a right view controller if and only if a tiny button is pulled left? Since I have multiple buttons on top of the map... is there a way to disable a few of them so they cannot be pulled left..but only leave one button that can be pulled left? Or is there any other solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I set the options for the PKRevealController as follows...

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{
PKRevealControllerRecognizesPanningOnFrontViewKey : @NO
};
```

and then I set the gesture panning property on my view object of the view controller. The below shows how to add the gesture panning property to a navigation bar.

```
    [frontViewController.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.revealController.revealPanGestureRecognizer];
```